# SAP Data Services 4.2 & PostgreSQL 10.5

Tags: sap-data-services

I need to populate a table by using SAP DS in PostgreSQL. I've been trying to find out if PostgreSQL 10.5 is supported by SAP Data Services 4.2, but I couldn't find a proper answer.
Does anybody know?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends what are you going to do.

It is not supported as a repository but cannot be added as data source or target on Windows-based SAP DS. Check pages 16 and 29 of [SAP Data Services PAM](https://support.sap.com/content/dam/launchpad/en_us/pam/pam-essentials/TIP/PAM_DataServices_4_2.pdf).

So in your case I assume the answer is **yes**. You can populate a table via DS.